# Using > and < inside a batch file, with a for loop

Tags: command-line, batch, pipe

When doing this inside a `test.bat` file:

```
for %%i in (__src\*.js) do jsmin <"%%i" >"temp\%%~ni%%~xi" "(C) Example"
```

I was expecting to see:

```
D:\Temp>jsmin <"__src\background.js" >"temp\background.js" "(C) Example"
```

but I see this instead:

```
D:\Temp>jsmin  "(C) Example" 0<"__src\background.js" 1>"temp\background.js"
```

Why this wrong order and `<` replaced by `0<` , `>` replaced by `1>`?

**How to get the normal order instead?** (as wanted by [jsmin](https://www.crockford.com/javascript/jsmin.html))

```
jsmin <fulljslint.js >jslint.js "(c)2002 Douglas Crockford"
```

Comment: The order and position of redirections is irrelevant, and unknown to the launched program. The preceding numerals emphasize the redirected paths, but don't have any effect (`0<` = `<` and `1>` = `>`). This is simply the way commands are echoed after expansion.

Comment: Yes but it still makes jsmin fail with wrong order...

Comment: @Basj If you are echo'ing then try `for %%i in (__src\*.js) do echo jsmin ^<"%%i" ^>"temp\%%~ni%%~xi" "(C) Example"` and the order is correct without the prefixed digits. Otherwise you might need to `setlocal enabledelayedexpasion` and set the substituted values as variables and then put those variables into the commands with the `!varnames!` like that perhaps. If you are just echo'ing though, that's how I resolved that by adding the caret symbols but I think you are trying to redirect with the jsmin command and I don't have that to test to confirm for you at the moment.

Comment: The program being run doesn't know where in the run string the redirections are being applied: it sees only the parameters. When command echoing in on, every redirection in a batch file is displayed in this way.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT I tried with `for %%i in (__src\*.js) do jsmin ^<"%%i" ^>"temp\%%~ni%%~xi" "(C) Example"` but it doesn't work

Comment: I have looked at the source code, and `jsmin` is a standard C program, which does nothing but read code from `stdin` and write modified code to `stdout`, with errors on `stderr`. What errors are you getting?

Comment: @AFH When using `for %%i in (__src\*.js) do jsmin ^<"%%i" ^>"temp\%%~ni%%~xi" "(C) Example"`, it does not return from `jsmin` and is blocked waiting for input. If you have time to have a look, here is the .exe: http://www.crockford.com/javascript/jsmin.zip

Comment: That command string is wrong - there is no redirection (the redirection strings are converted to parameters), so it reads from `stdin`. What errors do you get with your original command?

Answer (score 1):

I can't believe it, but the problem was only the newline. With this `test.bat`, it doesn't work properly (the copyright string is not added like jsmin should do it, and the first line of the output JS file is empty):

```
for %%i in (__src\*.js) do jsmin <"%%i" >"temp\%%~ni%%~xi" "(C) Example"
```

But with this `test.bat`, it works:

```
for %%i in (__src\*.js) do jsmin <"%%i" >"temp\%%~ni%%~xi" "(C) Example"
+ (empty line here)
```